# How to map a dynamic json property name with jackson for spring rest template request

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, resttemplate

I am trying to send request with rest template. normally it works but I need a dynamic jackson object for this type of data

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Name Of role",
  "permissions": {
    "global": [],
    "station": {
      "ID": [
        "String",
        "String",
        "String",
        "String"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

in this case I am trying to change property "ID" dynamically but I had bad luck with anygetter of jackson.
Normally I am creating my object with [jsonchema2pojo](https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/). and my objects are kinda big actually. I am doing something wrong but I can't see where for this problem. Or I am searching for wrong context on google.

additioanly here is the code generated for my request object:

```java
package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"id",
"name",
"permissions"
})
@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class CreateRoleRequestDto {

@JsonProperty("id")
private Integer id;
@JsonProperty("name")
private String name;
@JsonProperty("permissions")
private Permissions permissions;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

@JsonProperty("id")
public Integer getId() {
return id;
}

@JsonProperty("id")
public void setId(Integer id) {
this.id = id;
}

@JsonProperty("name")
public String getName() {
return name;
}

@JsonProperty("name")
public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

@JsonProperty("permissions")
public Permissions getPermissions() {
return permissions;
}

@JsonProperty("permissions")
public void setPermissions(Permissions permissions) {
this.permissions = permissions;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(CreateRoleRequestDto.class.getName()).append('@').append(Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(this))).append('[');
sb.append("id");
sb.append('=');
sb.append(((this.id == null)?"<null>":this.id));
sb.append(',');
sb.append("name");
sb.append('=');
sb.append(((this.name == null)?"<null>":this.name));
sb.append(',');
sb.append("permissions");
sb.append('=');
sb.append(((this.permissions == null)?"<null>":this.permissions));
sb.append(',');
sb.append("additionalProperties");
sb.append('=');
sb.append(((this.additionalProperties == null)?"<null>":this.additionalProperties));
sb.append(',');
if (sb.charAt((sb.length()- 1)) == ',') {
sb.setCharAt((sb.length()- 1), ']');
} else {
sb.append(']');
}
return sb.toString();
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
int result = 1;
result = ((result* 31)+((this.name == null)? 0 :this.name.hashCode()));
result = ((result* 31)+((this.id == null)? 0 :this.id.hashCode()));
result = ((result* 31)+((this.additionalProperties == null)? 0 :this.additionalProperties.hashCode()));
result = ((result* 31)+((this.permissions == null)? 0 :this.permissions.hashCode()));
return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
if (other == this) {
return true;
}
if ((other instanceof CreateRoleRequestDto) == false) {
return false;
}
CreateRoleRequestDto rhs = ((CreateRoleRequestDto) other);
return (((((this.name == rhs.name)||((this.name!= null)&&this.name.equals(rhs.name)))&&((this.id == rhs.id)||((this.id!= null)&&this.id.equals(rhs.id))))&&((this.additionalProperties == rhs.additionalProperties)||((this.additionalProperties!= null)&&this.additionalProperties.equals(rhs.additionalProperties))))&&((this.permissions == rhs.permissions)||((this.permissions!= null)&&this.permissions.equals(rhs.permissions))));
}

}

package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"global",
"station"
})
@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class Permissions {

@JsonProperty("global")
private List<Object> global = null;
@JsonProperty("station")
private Station station;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

@JsonProperty("global")
public List<Object> getGlobal() {
return global;
}

@JsonProperty("global")
public void setGlobal(List<Object> global) {
this.global = global;
}

@JsonProperty("station")
public Station getStation() {
return station;
}

@JsonProperty("station")
public void setStation(Station station) {
this.station = station;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(Permissions.class.getName()).append('@').append(Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(this))).append('[');
sb.append("global");
sb.append('=');
sb.append(((this.global == null)?"<null>":this.global));
sb.append(',');
sb.append("station");
sb.append('=');
sb.append(((this.station == null)?"<null>":this.station));
sb.append(',');
sb.append("additionalProperties");
sb.append('=');
sb.append(((this.additionalProperties == null)?"<null>":this.additionalProperties));
sb.append(',');
if (sb.charAt((sb.length()- 1)) == ',') {
sb.setCharAt((sb.length()- 1), ']');
} else {
sb.append(']');
}
return sb.toString();
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
int result = 1;
result = ((result* 31)+((this.station == null)? 0 :this.station.hashCode()));
result = ((result* 31)+((this.global == null)? 0 :this.global.hashCode()));
result = ((result* 31)+((this.additionalProperties == null)? 0 :this.additionalProperties.hashCode()));
return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
if (other == this) {
return true;
}
if ((other instanceof Permissions) == false) {
return false;
}
Permissions rhs = ((Permissions) other);
return ((((this.station == rhs.station)||((this.station!= null)&&this.station.equals(rhs.station)))&&((this.global == rhs.global)||((this.global!= null)&&this.global.equals(rhs.global))))&&((this.additionalProperties == rhs.additionalProperties)||((this.additionalProperties!= null)&&this.additionalProperties.equals(rhs.additionalProperties))));
}

}

package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"ID"
})
@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class Station {

@JsonProperty("ID")
private List<String> id = null;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

@JsonProperty("ID")
public List<String> getId() {
return id;
}

@JsonProperty("ID")
public void setId(List<String> id) {
this.id = id;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(Station.class.getName()).append('@').append(Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(this))).append('[');
sb.append("id");
sb.append('=');
sb.append(((this.id == null)?"<null>":this.id));
sb.append(',');
sb.append("additionalProperties");
sb.append('=');
sb.append(((this.additionalProperties == null)?"<null>":this.additionalProperties));
sb.append(',');
if (sb.charAt((sb.length()- 1)) == ',') {
sb.setCharAt((sb.length()- 1), ']');
} else {
sb.append(']');
}
return sb.toString();
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
int result = 1;
result = ((result* 31)+((this.id == null)? 0 :this.id.hashCode()));
result = ((result* 31)+((this.additionalProperties == null)? 0 :this.additionalProperties.hashCode()));
return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
if (other == this) {
return true;
}
if ((other instanceof Station) == false) {
return false;
}
Station rhs = ((Station) other);
return (((this.id == rhs.id)||((this.id!= null)&&this.id.equals(rhs.id)))&&((this.additionalProperties == rhs.additionalProperties)||((this.additionalProperties!= null)&&this.additionalProperties.equals(rhs.additionalProperties))));
}

}
```

Comment: can you show the JAVA POJO representing above json ? that will be easy to understand and fix

Comment: Hi I configured the json above and added the pojo generated. @Deadpool

in the Station class. ID property instead should be a dynamic like it can be 1 2 3 or any other string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are having `id` dynamically generated i will recommend to use `Map`

```
public class RequestData {

     private Map<String, String> slug; 

     public Map<String, List<String>> getSlug(){ 

       return properties; 

     } 

    public void add(String property, String List<String> value){ 

    properties.put(property, value); 

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

from my experience, if you're going to play with dynamic JSON object, like @Deadpool said, you can use `Map`, but my code is a little different cause i'm using <String, Object> rather than <String, List>. It depends on your needs. Besides, since you're using Spring Framework, it's cleaner if you're using Lombok library. From your code, you know how to use the annotation. So maybe you can use this code. I did implement this code in production environment and no issue 'till now.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class JSONRequestBody {

    Map<String, Object> data;
    
}
```